# Google geochart - arrow between countries

Tags: google-visualization

I need show arrow between countries in Google geochart. How do i do that?

Example : Chart "Number of tourists", Need to show the number of tourists flow between countries. One arrow from USA to Canada and another from Canada to USA, indicating the numbers on tooltips.